# Find rows numbers, add 1, then replace string

Tags: mysql

I have rows similar to this

`a:1:{s:5:"value";s:69:"https://www.mypage.com/files/products/product.jpg";}`

I would like to extract the number 69, add 1 and replace whole string with

`a:1:{s:5:"value";s:70:"https://www.mypage.com/files/products/product.jpg";}`

How to approach this? Is this possible to do in mysql?

I use mysql 5.5.

Thank you.

Comment: *"How to approach this? Is this possible to do in mysql?"* MySQL does not have a native PHP [serialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) parser, you should consider to use JSON instead or to normalize the data

Comment: The result would still be a broken serialization.

Comment: Consider upgrading to 8.0 (or MariaDB) in order to get `REGEXP_REPLACE()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this...

```
SELECT REPLACE(col, Substring_index(Substring_index(col, '"value";s:', -1), ':"http', 1),
              Cast(Substring_index(Substring_index(col, '"value";s:', -1), ':"http', 1) AS UNSIGNED) + 1) AS col
FROM   TableName
```

To update the data, do this.

```
UPDATE TableName
SET    col = REPLACE(col, Substring_index(Substring_index(col, '"value";s:', -1), ':"http', 1),
                          Cast(Substring_index(Substring_index(col, '"value";s:', -1), ':"http', 1) AS UNSIGNED) + 1);
```

Query step by step

Step 01

```
SELECT *
FROM   TableName

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                    col                                      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| a:1:{s:5:"value";s:69:"https://www.mypage.com/files/products/product.jpg";} |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Step 02 - *Get the value*

```
SELECT Substring_index(Substring_index(col, '"value";s:', -1), ':"http', 1)
FROM   TableName 

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Substring_index(Substring_index(col, '"value";s:', -1), ':"http', 1)  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                    69 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Step 03 - *Add +1*

```
SELECT Cast(Substring_index(Substring_index(col, '"value";s:', -1), ':"http', 1) AS UNSIGNED) + 1
FROM   TableName 

+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Cast(Substring_index(Substring_index(col, '"value";s:', -1), ':"http', 1) AS UNSIGNED) + 1  | 
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                                          70 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Step 04 - *Replace the value with new value*

```
SELECT REPLACE(col, Substring_index(Substring_index(col, '"value";s:', -1), ':"http', 1),
              Cast(Substring_index(Substring_index(col, '"value";s:', -1), ':"http', 1) AS UNSIGNED) + 1) AS col
FROM   TableName 

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                    col                                      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| a:1:{s:5:"value";s:70:"https://www.mypage.com/files/products/product.jpg";} |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Online Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=9df7f1b01e7a8fa33ccc1c222dd3b411

Comment: Hi, this works great. I had to remove the parts with " " " - which is apparently wrong syntax in mysql 5.5. However the new data is not written to database, I only see the correct result on screen. This is my testing code SELECT REPLACE(content, Substring_index(Substring_index(content, ';s:', -1), ':', 1),
              Cast(Substring_index(Substring_index(content, ';s:', -1), ':', 1) AS UNSIGNED) + 1) AS content
FROM   nodewords where id ='1' and name = 'og:image' and content like '%http%'

Comment: I managet do make it work like this "UPDATE `nodewords`
 SET content = REPLACE(content, Substring_index(Substring_index(content, ';s:', -1), ':', 1),
              Cast(Substring_index(Substring_index(content, ';s:', -1), ':', 1) AS UNSIGNED) + 1)  where id ='1' and name = 'og:image' and content like '%http%'" . Thank you very much for help

Comment: You're welcome. Thank you for selecting this as the accepted answer.